# /.bin/webpack Webpack command not found after Node nvm update in prod env

Tags: node.js, webpack, travis-ci, nvm

After upgrading my project from using Node v5.0.0 to 6.10.2 (via nvm), my Travis build is now failing with the error:

`/home/travis/build/Widen/gray-wolf/node_modules/.bin/webpack --config config/webpack.config.js -p
make: /home/travis/build/Widen/gray-wolf/node_modules/.bin/webpack: Command not found
make: *** [webpack] Error 127`

In our MAKE scripts, the commands ultimately being called are as followed:

`npm install` (this does not seem to be failing)

`$(NPM_BIN)/webpack --config config/webpack.config.js -p`

Following `npm install`, one of the lines is:

`webpack@2.3.3 node_modules/webpack` before the webpack command fails

The ways where this is not failing are

1. nvm version is set to 5.0.0 instead of 6.10.2
2. It's in a stage environment instead of prod environment

The initial failure happened alongside a large amount of updated dependencies, so I limited the change to only update Node with nvm with the following commands in my `.travis.yml` file:

`install:
 - . $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh
 - nvm install 6.10.2
 - nvm use 6.10.2`

The only difference being the version number. Following that failure, I'm getting another similar failure with eslint. It seems likely that the failures have the same cause.

`make: /home/travis/build/Widen/gray-wolf/node_modules/.bin/eslint: Command not found`

Comment: This was caused because we were using a `IS_CI` symbol for Travis. If CI is true, we need to run `npm install --production=false`. Unfortunately I could not find a way to install both the depedencies and the devdependencies without using this deprecated flag.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a prod environment but the travis flag of `IS_CI` is set to true, use the (deprecated) `--production=false` flag.